# Coffee source maps on staging (uglified)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to get source maps for **uglified** JS in Rails 3?

I am currently using code from https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps and that works great for development, but after turning on assets precompilation and (most importantly) uglifying and turning debug assets off, it won't work (since it's not designed to).

Uglifier seems to support source maps, and the new coffee-script-source supports source maps also. I've tried hacking around sprockets a bit but I wasn't able to find a solution.

So basically what I have is *.coffee -> *.js -> application.js (uglified), I want to at least get back to the javascript source (un-unglified), but ideally of course to get back to the coffeescript.

Is this possible in Rails 3? With any monkey-patching or anything that is necessary.

Comment: The step *.coffee -> *.js is supported by the coffeescript compiler, but if you then concatenate the javascript files together, the source maps that came out of this first step has to be rewritten. I am not sure if there is anything that supports that. If you can work without concatenating the files, it should be possible to do with the tools you already have.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to go in this direction but it's a bit too much work. It seems there is some work being done towards this in sprockets-rails (Rails 4), but it's not compatible with Rails 3.
I couldn't even get uglifier source maps to work (without caring for the coffee maps).

Comment: The uglifier source maps works for me, but I haven't tested it thoroughly and expect that its going to be a bumpy ride.

Comment: How did you manage to make that work with asset pipeline? Could you gist it?

Comment: Sorry, @mrbrdo - I'm not using Ruby.

Comment: Ah well, that is the core of my problem, making it work with assets pipeline :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is some ongoing work to make this all work together with the asset pipeline, but it's not done yet. See [this pull request](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/311) for more info.